# Does Spellbane stop Wish from transporting into its area of effect?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e

I'm specifically trying to figure out whether or not *[Spellbane](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/aroden-s-spellbane/)* can stop the "regardless of local conditions" clause for a caster using [Wish](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wish) to transport into an area guarded against it.

> Transport travelers. A *wish* can lift one creature per caster level from anywhere on any plane and place those creatures anywhere else on any plane regardless of local conditions. An unwilling target gets a Will save to negate the effect, and spell resistance (if any) applies.

Suppose a wizard wants to stop intruders from using *Wish* to transport into an area of his personal plane. By RAW, could he achieve that by casting *Spellbane* to block *Wish*?

My guess is the answer is up to DM interpretation.

Comment: So just to clarify, someone has cast *Spellbane* to prevent *Wish* in a certain area. And someone else wants to use *Wish* to transport into that area. Is that the case you're asking about?

Comment: Yeah that's correct. Essentially can Dan the Mega Wizard stop pesky Intruders from using Wish to get into his super cool personal plane by using Spellbane to block Wishes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for providing that information. I've edited the post so that your intended question is clearer. Very interesting question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Spellbane stops Wish

The description of [Spellbane](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/aroden-s-spellbane/) states (emphasis mine):

> Select one spell per five caster levels at the time of casting. The spells selected cannot be changed after the spell is cast. **This spell otherwise functions like *antimagic field***, except its emanation only prevents the functioning of the selected spells.
>
> [...]
>
> This spell can even negate an *antimagic field*, another instance of this spell, or any spell that specifies immunity to *antimagic field* (such as *wall of force*, *prismatic sphere*, and *prismatic wall*). Multiple *spellbane* effects can overlap. Their effects stack, preventing the functioning of every spell targeted by any of the multiple *spellbane* emanations. Spell effects created by artifacts or deities cannot be suppressed by this spell.

And the description of [how antimagic fields work](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Antimagic) states (emphasis mine):

> An ***antimagic*** field spell or **effect** cancels magic altogether. An
>   antimagic effect has the following powers and characteristics.
>
> 1. **No** supernatural ability, spell-like ability, or **spell works** in an area of antimagic (but extraordinary abilities still work).
>
> [...]
>
> 9. *Wall of force*, *prismatic wall*, and *prismatic sphere* are not affected by antimagic. [...]

By RAW, *antimagic field*s prevent **any and all** spells from functioning. There are some exceptions as noted, but *Wish* is **not** one of them (and even if it were, *Spellbane* affects spells immune to *antimagic field*s).

Note, however, that if the *Wish* is cast from an artifact or deity, the teleportation would take effect. Effects from *Wish* are different than effects from artifacts, but effects from *Miracle* come from deities. To this respect, see  [Can Miracle overcome Dimensional Lock/Antimagic Field?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/136353/can-miracle-overcome-dimensional-lock-antimagic-field/136385)

Specifically addressing your "local conditions" concern: Even though [Pathfinder 1e doesn't have a "specific beats general" rule](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62373/where-do-i-find-the-specific-beats-general-rule), the wording of "local conditions" is too vague and does **not** explicitly address anti-teleportation measures. My interpretation of RAW is the same than [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119330/is-there-a-spell-that-is-a-combination-of-gate-and-transport/119372#119372), quote:

> [Wish] doesn't explicitly bypass teleportation barriers, but it does lack the teleportation subschool and is of the rare 'universal' school which can help with some defenses. A generous GM may read 'regardless of local conditions' as bypassing certain teleportation barriers, but that's really referring to the difficulty spells ordinarily have placing creatures in spaces that are intrinsically hostile to them (like inside solid rock or a fish out of water or whatnot).

However...

## Intruders can exploit Wish to move *as close as possible*

Potential intruders can just wish to be transported to a **oddly specific** location, e.g.: «I wish that me and my present companions be transported to the place allowing us the easiest safe access to [very specific object or creature]»

Making a wish in that way metaphysically bypasses the problem: the wish itself can probe the whole plane in search for all kinds of defenses (including *antimagic field*s, *dimensional anchor*s, *et al*) in order to calculate the best possible approach point. That means right next to the target is the *wish* itself decides that it can bypass *spellbane*, and the place with the weakest defenses in other case.